# How to add better video button to Quill.js

Tags: quill

i try to figure out how to work with Quill.js.

I want the user to add a video BUT it should be saved in a special format.

- If the user clicks on the video button, he should input the URL to the video...
- then there should be a visual placeholder added to the editor. If the user clicks on that placeholder, he can change the video url or delete it
- the Video-Code should look like this: [video=http...] so the system can replace it...

Is this possible in Quill.js?
This is what i tried so far:

```
<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="bold"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>
  <button id="italic"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button>
  <button id="video"><i class="fa fa-video"></i></button>
</div>

<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  
  let Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');

  class BoldBlot extends Inline { }
  BoldBlot.blotName = 'bold';
  BoldBlot.tagName = 'strong';

  class ItalicBlot extends Inline { }
  ItalicBlot.blotName = 'italic';
  ItalicBlot.tagName = 'em';
  
  class VideoBlot extends Inline {
    static create(value) {
      let node = super.create();
      // Sanitize url value if desired
      node.setAttribute('href', value);
      // Okay to set other non-format related attributes
      // These are invisible to Parchment so must be static
      node.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      return node;
    }

    static formats(node) {
      // We will only be called with a node already
      // determined to be a Link blot, so we do
      // not need to check ourselves
      return node.getAttribute('href');
    }
  }
  VideoBlot.blotname = 'video';
  VideoBlot.tagName = 'video-tag';

  Quill.register(BoldBlot);
  Quill.register(ItalicBlot);
  Quill.register(VideoBlot);
  
    // Initialize as you would normally
    var quill = new Quill('#editor');
  
  
  $('#bold').click(function() {
     quill.format('bold', true);
  });
  $('#italic').click(function() {
    quill.format('italic', true);
  });
  $('#video').click(function() {
  let value = prompt('Enter link URL');
  quill.format('video-tag', value);
});
  
});

console.log(Quill.imports);
```

https://codepen.io/kili123/pen/eYQgEwv